# How to change the icon of Share Provider?

Tags: android

There is a share function in my app.I'm using `ShareProvider` to make it.It run very well,but it appear icon like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RDNJO.png)

In the right of toolbar ,We can see two icons,but i just need [this icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RSxBN.png)

Anyone have some method to resolve the problem?

Comment: your question is not clean, can you elaborate the problem ?

Comment: so you not able to see that message icon..right post your toolbar XML or give margin properly.

Comment: Look in your `onCreateOptionsMenu` look for the xml that is inflated. Inside that find icon in your menu xml file and remove it.

Comment: Just like the first image,have two icons in the right of toolbar,right? Now ,i just need share icon.

Answer (score 0):

Am not sure you trying same but according to your first image i thought like this.

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
            android:gravity="right">
        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_share"
            android:gravity="right"
           />
            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:src="@drawable/ic_inbox"
                />
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

hope it may help.